# DreamWeaver with PHP

Tags: php, dreamweaver

Greetings ! I have a project that has php index.php file in /htdocs. Also include files like dboperaitons.php, config.php and css file also in /htdocs/themes. Now I set up New site in dreamweaver opened the index.php file, it is running fine , but when I click on properties and ry to add or modify css property from dreamweaver, it gives me error saying unable to open file http://localhost/themes/en.css file because it is not found in the hard disk.
1. Why is it searching for file as http://localhost instead of c:/xampp/themes.
2. It says en.css file is remote file and cannot be edited.

How can I resolve this. Please guide.

Comment: You've probably referenced the CSS file that way in your HTML output. Use a relative path instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can fix this problem by browsing the file manually from its location.

Answer (score 0):

When you define a site in Dreamweaver you need to make sure you set up both the local and remote locations in order for it to know where files are.  It sounds like you have not defined the local site folders properly and DW is confused about where things go.